# Paypal button over on sticky

Tags: wordpress, sticky-footer

I have a problem with PayPal button on my Flatsome child WordPress theme. When scrolling down, the PayPal button stays over the sticky.

I tried to find a function in the theme to fix the problem, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase z-index of header part.

Try adding this css.

```
header#header {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
in which file should i add it? Maybe in style.css ? Thanks

Comment: you have to add this css in you child theme style.css.